# qsub -t job "has died"

Tags: hpc, pbs, qsub

I am trying to submit an array job to our cluster using qsub. The script is like:

```
#!/bin/bash 
#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=1              # Number of nodes and processor 
#.....  (Other options)
#PBS -t 0-50                       # List job

cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR
./programname << EOF
some parameters
EOF
```

This script runs without a problem when removing `-t` option. But every time I added `-t`, I got following output:

```
---------------------------------------------
Check nodes and clean them of stray processes
---------------------------------------------
Checking node XXXXXXXXXX
-> User XXXX  running job XXXXX.XXX:state=X:ncpus=X
-> Job XXX.XXX has died
Done clearing all the allocated nodes
------------------------------------------------------
Concluding PBS prologue script - XX-XX-XXXX XX:XX:XX
------------------------------------------------------
--------------  Job will be requeued  --------------
```

Where it died and started requeue. No error message. I did not find any similar issue online. Has anyone experienced this before? Thank you!

(I wrote another "manual" array qsub script which works. But I do wish to get the work, as it is in the command option and much cleaner.)